# Drawing ellipse with Bresenham's algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry, drawing, ellipse

**Hello,**

I'm trying to draw an ellipse, which is parallel to the orthogonal system, using Bresenham's algorithm. I want to draw the **top-left (W,SW,S)** quarter of the ellipse, and then deduce others.

[image: what i want to draw]

To do this, i'm using an **incremental algorithm with the second-order logic**. I did it from another algorithm that draw the **top-right quarter** first, but what i'm doing isn't working.

The problem appears when the 2nd region is drawing, and I don't know where it comes from.

You can see what I have (black), and what I expect (green):
(center of the ellipse (xc, yc) and the upper right button (x2,y2) that is ~(xc+30,yc+20) in this example)
[image: DOTS]
(a is abs(x2-xc), and b is abs(y2-yc))
The first parameter is the middle of the ellipse (xc, yc), the second is the upper right point established the x and y radius. You can see the ellipse goes too far (2 points on the left and on the right). You can see an other example
(center of the ellipse (xc, yc) and the upper right button (x2,y2) that is ~(xc+15,yc+18) in this example)
[image: oexa]

The algorithm is deduced from the incremental algorithm with the second-order logic.

Here is my code, (a is abs(x2-xc), and b is abs(y2-yc))

```
ellipse(int a, int b, int xc, int yc) {
    int a2 = a*a, b2 = b*b;
    int x = 0, y = b; //Starting point

    int incSW = b2*2 + a2*2;

    int deltaW = b2*(-2*x + 3); //deduced from incremental algorithm with the second-order logic
    int deltaS = a2*(-2*y + 3);
    int deltaSW = deltaW + deltaS;

    int d1 = b2 - a2*b + a2/4; //dp starting value in the first region
    int d2 = b2*(x - 0.5)*(x - 0.5) + a2*(y - 1)*(y - 1) - a2*b2; //dp starting value in the second region

    //First region
    while(a2*(y-0.5) >= b2*(-x-1)) {
        DrawPixel(g,-x+xc, -y+yc); // 1st case
        DrawPixel(g,-x+xc, y+yc); // 2nd case
        DrawPixel(g,x+xc, y+yc); // 3rd case
        DrawPixel(g,x+xc, -y+yc); // 4th case
        if(d1>0) {
            d1+=deltaSW;
            deltaW+=b2*2;
            deltaSW+=incSW;
            y--;
        }
        else {
            d1+=deltaW;
            deltaW+=2*b2;
            deltaSW+=2*b2;
        }
        x--;
    }

    deltaSW = b2*(2 - 2*x) + a2*(-2*y + 3);

    //Second region
    while(y>=0) {
        DrawPixel(g,-x+xc, -y+yc); // 1st case
        DrawPixel(g,-x+xc, y+yc); // 2nd case
        DrawPixel(g,x+xc, y+yc); // 3rd case
        DrawPixel(g,x+xc, -y+yc); // 4th case
        if(d2>0) {
            d2+=deltaS;
            deltaS+=a2*2;
            deltaSW+=a2*2;
        }
        else {
            d2+=deltaSW;
            deltaSW+=incSW;
            deltaS+=a2*2;
            x--;
        }
        y--;
    }
}
```

I hope you can help me, thanks.

Comment: You probably should also add to the question numeric values of the parameters for your example images.

Comment: Ok, i just did it :)

Comment: OrsCrous, that's not **_numeric_** values! Do you expect readers to count pixels on the image by hand? Or how others are supposed to get values for `a` and `b`?

Comment: i think i did something better, thanks

Comment: `top-left (W,SW,S)` if I take `W` to stand for west: what does `S` stand for?

Comment: S is for south. If you are on the point 0,b, you have 3 choices : drawing the west, south west or south.

Comment: (It could have been drawing in the western/southern half-plane, the south-western quadrant - among uncounted other things.) "The offsets" (`+3`, especially) look fishy - is there a presentation of the algorithm you are trying to follow? (I'm never sure whether to use two loops or one - even after factoring out `draw(cx, cy, x, y)`.)

Comment: I try to do something like that http://www.cpp.edu/~raheja/CS445/MEA.pdf , but for the opposite way (from (0,b) to (-a,0), where a is the horizontal radius, and b the vertical radius)

Answer (score 1):

Using the error term e = a x^2 + b y^2 - r^2, it's pretty easy to show that a step from (x,y) to (x,y+1) changes the error by 2by + b, a step to (x+1,y+1) by 2ax + a + 2by + b, and a step to (x+1,y) by 2ax + a.

Starting from a point (-x0, 0), choose the least absolute error step from these three. The first two cases are the norm for the "first region" as you call it.

The first time a step right, (x,y) to (x+1,y), produces least error, you know you're in the second region. At this point the first case is no longer needed. The quarter ellipse can be finished using only the second two cases.

Note this check avoids the floating point operations you've used. The whole point of Bresenham-ish algorithms is to avoid floating point.

The last bit to notice is that you don't want to compute 2ax or 2by each iteration. The multiplications can be avoided by maintaining variables, say dx=2ax and dy=2by, and updating them. A step from x to x+1 increments dx by 2a, a constant.  Similarly a step from y to y+1 increments dy by 2b.

Putting all this together, you get the (rough) code below.

Note that you can check the incremental error computation by verifying it against the original error term. If (x0,0) is the initial point, then you know x0^2 = r^2. So the actual error in every iteration is a * x^2 + b * y^2 - x0^2.  This ought to equal `e` in the code below, and it does.

```
import static java.lang.Math.abs;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;

public class EllipseTracer {
  static char [] [] raster = new char[51][101]; 

  static void trace(int x, int y, int a, int b, BiConsumer<Integer, Integer> emitter) {
    emitter.accept(x, y);
    int e = 0;
    int dx = 2 * a * x;
    int dy = 2 * b * y;
    // First region: stepping north and northeast.
    while (x < 0) {
      int dxa = dx + a;
      int dyb = dy + b;
      int eUp = e + dyb;
      int eRt = e + dxa;
      int eDg = e + dxa + dyb;
      if (abs(eUp) < abs(eDg)) {
        emitter.accept(x, ++y);
        e = eUp;
        dy += 2 * b;
      } else {
        if (abs(eRt) < abs(eDg)) {
          // Step east is least error. Found second region.
          emitter.accept(++x, y);
          e = eRt;
          dx += 2 * a;
          break;
        }
        emitter.accept(++x, ++y);
        e = eDg;
        dy += 2 * b;
        dx += 2 * a;
      }
    }
    // Second region: step northeast and east.
    while (x < 0) {
      int dxa = dx + a;
      int dyb = dy + b;
      int eRt = e + dxa;
      int eDg = e + dxa + dyb;
      if (abs(eRt) < abs(eDg)) {
        emitter.accept(++x, y);
        e = eRt;
        dx += 2 * a;
      } else {
        emitter.accept(++x, ++y);
        e = eDg;
        dy += 2 * b;
        dx += 2 * a;
      }
    }
  }

  static void emit(int x, int y) {
    raster[y][x + 100] = '*';
  }

  public static void main(String [] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < raster.length; ++i) {
      Arrays.fill(raster[i], ' ');
    }
    trace(-100, 0, 1, 4, EllipseTracer::emit);
    for (int i = 0; i < raster.length; ++i) {
      System.out.println(raster[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

You can add more tricks to avoid the absolute values, but I'll let you look for those.

Comment: So if I have to do this from 0,b to -a,0, I guess I just have to add some - and it should work. I will try it

Comment: @OrsCrous No, of course you can do the math on any quadrant you want. I picked this because it makes all the slopes positive, so there's no chance of making a  mistake with a negative sign.

Comment: @OrsCrous If this answer is helpful it would be nice if you accepted it.